# How to debug why this code is giving error?

Tags: php

Still wondering why its not working.

```
echo "<a  href="&quot;$config_basedir. &quot;/products.php?id=&quot; . $catrow[">". $catrow['name'] . "</a>";}
```

I wanted to use a variable for the `products.php?id=&quot.`. Is there another way to solve this?

Comment: use htmlentities function

Comment: just add 4 spaces on the markdown editor to properly format your question as a "code", plus, you need to escape the quotes

Comment: Hi Joe. I've trimmed some fairly insistent begging from your posts. May I ask you not to add this sort of material, please? It is distracting for future readers, and irritating to people who otherwise would want to help you. Remember that people here are volunteers, and that they should not be pressured into giving more time than they have capacity for. It is best to address people with the professionalism you would use with a colleague: ask politely, but without pleading. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this...

```html
$catrow_name = $catrow['name'];
$config_basedir = $config_basedir."/products.php?id=$catrow_name";
echo '<a  href="'.$config_basedir.'">'.$catrow['name'].'</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

There is some issue in using quote in your code, please see the below code:

```
echo '<a href="'.$config_basedir.'/products.php?id='.$catrow['name'].'">'.$catrow['name'].'</a>';
```

You can get value of `id` from URL as: `$id = $_GET["id"];`

Answer (score -1):

You really don't need the `&quot;` . I think there is also a curly brace at the end of your which is also a possible problem. Kindly post the error php throws in your browser for more clarification

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '" href="' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\wamp\www\shopcart\action\bar.php on line 13

Comment: Rewrite your php statement to look like this `echo '<a  href="'.$config_basedir .'/products.php?id='.$catrow[">". $catrow['name'].' "></a>';`